# LibGdx close Window

Tags: java, libgdx

I've one problem with LibGdx. I have a "MainGameScreen" class and a coustom Window(scene2d Ui) class.  I have a "TextButton" in my Window. What is the best way to close the window when the button is pressed ? Thanks !

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is add a ChangeListener to the button which closes the window whenever the button is pressed.

Here is a small demo of how you could do it:

```
// The window has to be final to be accessible from our listener.
final Window window = new Window("Title", skin);

// Create our button.
TextButton button = new TextButton("Press me to close window!", skin);

// Here we add a click listener to our button.
button.addListener (new ChangeListener() {
    // This method is called whenever the actor is clicked. We override its behavior here.
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        // This is where we remove the window.
        window.remove();
    }
});

// Add the button to our window.
window.add(button);

// Add the window to our stage.
stage.addActor(window);
```

Comment: That is not best practice.
I highly recommend to use a ClickListener, because the button needs to be clicked. Changelistener may be fired, if you do not think so.

Comment: Actually @Keey is wrong on that, `ChangeListener` is a best practice to handle button clicks - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#changeevents